# Same interface different ctor implementaion

Tags: c#, oop

I have and in interface  `ICalibrationToolsLoader`

```
namespace Utilities.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICalibrationToolsLoader
    {            
        string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null);
        IspSectionUiSettings GetIspSectionUiSettings();
        List<CalibrationGroup> GetCmcGroupOrder();            
    }
}
```

and two classes implements it.

```
public class Ipu6CalibraitionToolsLoader : ICalibrationToolsLoader
{
       private string _selectedSensorType;
       public Ipu6CalibraitionToolsLoader(string selectedSensorType)
       {
           _selectedSensorType = selectedSensorType;
           _ispSectionUiSettings = Serialization.DataContract.Deserialize<IspSectionUiSettings>(GetDefaultIspFile(_selectedSensorType));
            InitCmcOrder();
       }

       public string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null)
       {
           string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
           string pathSuffix = null;
           switch ((IPU6SensorType)Enum.Parse(typeof(IPU6SensorType), selectedSensorType))
           {
               case IPU6SensorType.None:
                   break;
               case IPU6SensorType.Bayer:
                   pathSuffix = "IPUs\\IPU6\\IPU6DefaultsIspFile.xml";
                   break;
               case IPU6SensorType.MD:
                   pathSuffix = "IPUs\\IPU6\\IPU6MdDefaultsIspFile.xml";
                   break;                
               default:
                   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("selectedSensorType", selectedSensorType, null);
            }

            if (pathSuffix != null)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(location, pathSuffix);
                return path;
            }
            throw new Exception("missing defaultIspFileXml");
        }

    public void InitCmcOrder()
    {
        _cmcCalibrationToolsOrder = new List<CalibrationGroup>
        {
            CalibrationGroup.GeneralDataTools,
            CalibrationGroup.SensorAndModuleSettingsTools,
            CalibrationGroup.LateralChromaticAberrationTool,
        };
    }
}
```

```
public class Ipu4CalibraitionToolsLoader : ICalibrationToolsLoader
{
    public Ipu4CalibraitionToolsLoader()
    {
        _ispSectionUiSettings = Serialization.DataContract.Deserialize<IspSectionUiSettings>(GetDefaultIspFile());
        InitCmcOrder();
    }

    public string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null)
    {
        string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string pathSuffix = "IPUs\\Broxton\\IPU4DefaultsIspFile.xml";
        string path = Path.Combine(location, pathSuffix);
        return path;
    }

    public void InitCmcOrder()
    {
        _cmcCalibrationToolsOrder = new List<CalibrationGroup>
        {
            CalibrationGroup.GeneralDataTools,
            CalibrationGroup.SensorAndModuleSettingsTools,
            CalibrationGroup.LateralChromaticAberrationTool,
        };
    }
}
```

basically most of the functions are the same however, functions like the constructor and GetDefaultIsp needs to have different implementation.

I tried to use inheritance but calling a virtual function inside the constructor is a big NO NO.
Can you suggest of another way of doing so?

having 2 classes using the same interface however some methods should have different implementation?

I don't want to have another function like Init() which needs to be called after the constructor.

Comment: Could we see the Interface definition?

Comment: Please show us the complete source code for the interface and the two classes.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I added the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Addition of the IoC implementation to solve your issue!

## IoC Version

The IoC solution is, in my opinion, way more elegant but probably a little bit more complicated to maintain when you are not used to IoC.

Credits goes to `plalx` for suggesting it in the comments :D.

```
// There is no need for an interface anymore (but you can keep it of course)
public class IpuCalibrationToolsLoader
{
    private string _selectedSensorType;
    private string _ispSectionUiSettings;
    private List<CalibrationGroup> _cmcCalibrationToolsOrder;

    public IIspFileProvider Provider { get; private set; }

    // Notice the internal constructor. No one will be able to create an instance of IpuCalibrationToolsLoader out of your assembly except the factory
    internal IpuCalibrationToolsLoader(IIspFileProvider provider, string selectedSensorType = null)
    {
        this.Provider = provider;
        _selectedSensorType = selectedSensorType;

        _ispSectionUiSettings = Serialization.DataContract.Deserialize<IspSectionUiSettings>(provider.GetDefaultIspFile(_selectedSensorType));

        this.InitCmcOrder();
    }

    public void InitCmcOrder()
    {
        _cmcCalibrationToolsOrder = new List<CalibrationGroup>
        {
            CalibrationGroup.GeneralDataTools,
            CalibrationGroup.SensorAndModuleSettingsTools,
            CalibrationGroup.LateralChromaticAberrationTool,
        };
    }

    [..] // Since the Provider is exposed as a properties of your IpuCalibrationClassLoader, there is no need for defining the GetDefaultIspFile methods within this class
}

public interface IIspFileProvider
{
    string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null);
}

public class Ipu6FileProvider : IIspFileProvider
{
    public string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null)
    {
        string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string pathSuffix = null;
        switch ((IPU6SensorType)Enum.Parse(typeof(IPU6SensorType), selectedSensorType))
        {
            case IPU6SensorType.None:
                break;
            case IPU6SensorType.Bayer:
                pathSuffix = "IPUs\\IPU6\\IPU6DefaultsIspFile.xml";
                break;
            case IPU6SensorType.MD:
                pathSuffix = "IPUs\\IPU6\\IPU6MdDefaultsIspFile.xml";
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("selectedSensorType", selectedSensorType, null);
        }

        if (pathSuffix != null)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(location, pathSuffix);
            return path;
        }
        throw new Exception("missing defaultIspFileXml");
    }
}

public class Ipu4FileProvider : IIspFileProvider
{
    public string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null)
    {
        string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string pathSuffix = "IPUs\\Broxton\\IPU4DefaultsIspFile.xml";
        string path = Path.Combine(location, pathSuffix);
        return path;
    }
}

public static class IpuCalibrationToolsLoaderFactory
{
    public static IpuCalibrationToolsLoader GetIpu4CalibrationToolsLoader()
    {
        return new IpuCalibrationToolsLoader(new Ipu4FileProvider());
    }

    public static IpuCalibrationToolsLoader GetIpu6CalibrationToolsLoader(string selectedSensorType)
    {
        return new IpuCalibrationToolsLoader(new Ipu6FileProvider(), selectedSensorType);
    }
}
```

## Inheritance version

Here is the version using an abstract class. An abstract class is a class you cannot instantiate. It only holds some code:

```
public abstract class BaseCalibrationToolsLoader : ICalibrationToolsLoader
{
    public BaseCalibrationToolsLoader()
    {
        // put here the shared constructor code
        _cmcCalibrationToolsOrder = new List<CalibrationGroup>
        {
            CalibrationGroup.GeneralDataTools,
            CalibrationGroup.SensorAndModuleSettingsTools,
            CalibrationGroup.LateralChromaticAberrationTool,
        };
    }

    public List<CalibrationGroup> GetCmcGroupOrder()
    {
        // Put here the shared code among the two implementation
    }

    // As the implementation is different, you declare the method abstract so you only implement it in the concret classes
    public abstract string GetDefaultIspFile(string selectedSensorType = null);
}
```

Now, you can create your concrete implementation that derived from the abstract class:

```
public class Ipu4CalibraitionToolsLoader : BaseCalibrationToolsLoader 
{
    public Ipu4CalibraitionToolsLoader ()
        : base() // <- call the protected constructor
    {
        // put here the specific implementation constructor code
        // notice that the constructor of the abstract class will **ALWAYS** be call before this code
        _ispSectionUiSettings = Serialization.DataContract.Deserialize<IspSectionUiSettings>(GetDefaultIspFile());
    }

    // The GetCmcGroupOrder is already implemented, nothing to do about it

    // With the sealed keyword, the method cannot be overriden in another class
    public sealed override void GetDefaultIsp(string selectedSensorType = null)
    {
        // put here the concrete implementation for Ipu4
    }
}

public class Ipu6CalibraitionToolsLoader: BaseCalibrationToolsLoader 
{
    public Ipu6CalibraitionToolsLoader(string selectedSensorType)
        : base() // <- call the protected constructor
    {
        // put here the specific implementation constructor code
        // notice that the constructor of the abstract class will **ALWAYS** be call before this code
        _selectedSensorType = selectedSensorType;
        _ispSectionUiSettings = Serialization.DataContract.Deserialize<IspSectionUiSettings>(GetDefaultIspFile(_selectedSensorType));
    }

    // The GetCmcGroupOrder is already implemented, nothing to do about it

    // With the sealed keyword, the method cannot be overriden in another class
    public sealed override void GetDefaultIsp(string selectedSensorType = null)
    {
        // put here the concrete implementation for Ipu6
    }
}
```

As for the abstract constructor, you can define a virtual method in the abstract class and call it in the concrete implementation, in order to share a part of the code:

```
public abstract class BaseCalibrationToolsLoader : ICalibrationToolsLoader
{
    [..]

    // By using the virtual keyword, you allow your method to be overriden in the derived classes
    public virtual void PartiallySharedMethod()
    {
        // Shared implementation
    }

    [..]
}
```

And in the concrete implementations:

```
public class Ipu4CalibraitionToolsLoader : BaseCalibrationToolsLoader 
{
    [..]

    public override void PartiallySharedMethod()
    {
        // Unlike in the constructor, you can call the base method whenever you want.
        // Some specific code can came here
        base.PartiallySharedMethod();
        // And other specific code can also came here
    }

    [..]
}

public class Ipu6CalibraitionToolsLoader: BaseCalibrationToolsLoader 
{
    [..]

    public override void PartiallySharedMethod()
    {
        // Unlike in the constructor, you can call the base method whenever you want.
        // Some specific code can came here
        base.PartiallySharedMethod();
        // And other specific code can also came here
    }

    [..]
}
```

Comment: thanks, however I do not understand how does it solve the call of a virtual function.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the content of your virtual function. If it is shared code, just put it into the abstract class constructor. If it is implementation specific code, just put it into the associated constructor.

Comment: it is not a shared code, i have a specific implementation for of the same function for each derived class, this is why I need something like a virtual function, however I want to enforce the classes to call this function on creation of a new instance.

Comment: Then you just have to call it in each concrete constructor. But what is the point of providing a function if it is already called by the constructor?

Comment: Please look at the code above, I added more code to show you the difference.

Comment: You can `sealed` the `GetDefaultIspFile` method in the concrete implementations. This way the method is no longer `virtual`.

Comment: Take a look to my last edit, taking into account your edit.

Comment: What about composition here, were you'd have a concrete `IpuCalibrationToolsLoader` class which can be configured with a `DefaultIspFileProvider`. You could then have a factory with a `createIpu2CalibrationToolsLoader` and `createIpu4CalibrationToolsLoader` which would essentially do something like `return new IpuCalirationToolsLoader(..., new SensorBasedDefaultIspFileProvider(new Dictionnary<string, string>() { {"bayer", "IPUs\\IPU6\\IPU6DefaultsIspFile.xml"}, ...})` for the up2 and perhaps use a `new SingleFileDefaultIspFileProvider("IPUs\\Broxton\\IPU4DefaultsIspFile.xml")` for ipu4.

Comment: That would be very elegant in my opinion (every solution based on IoC are to me ^^). But as all solution involving IoC, it may be a bit more complex.

Comment: @plalx I can use IOC, we are using windsor castle, care to share your code in a full answer?

Comment: @Gilad I'm not a C# programmer ;) Essentially it boils down to this... right now you factor commonalities into a base abstract class and you implement differences by overriding methods on child classes. Instead of doing that you can factor commonalities in a concrete class and make it configurable in order to support the differences (strategy pattern). By configurable I mean that you identify the points of change between the various calibration tools loaders, then you define a contract (interface) to make these point of change explicit.

Comment: For instance if the only thing that differs is that one loader returns a path bound to a specific sensor while the other returns the same path independently of the sensor then you just need one concrete `IpuCalibrationToolsLoader` class that can be configured with a `DefaultIpsFileProvider` strategy where you'd have 2 different implementations.

Comment: Now the only part left is to assemble these objects together to create either an Ipu2 or Ipu4 loader. That problem can be solved using a static factory or I guess an IOC too.

Comment: @Gilad take a look to my new edit. I just added an IoC solution based on plalx suggestion.

Comment: @plalx take a look to my new edit. Do not hesitate to improve it if I made a mistake in my implementation.